# display the "alpha" char in winforms

Tags: winforms

I need to show the "α" sign on a winform.
Tried simply to do "\u0224" but it doesn`t do the trick.
Went over with a loop like this

```
for (int index = 48; index < 255; index++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(index.ToString() + ": " + (char)index + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

But it doesn`t show the "α" sign at all.

Any ideas on how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Due to some limitations I could not use other options - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it solved with `'\u03b1'.ToString()`

Comment: Why would you, to get a string literal of length 1, use a character constant and call `ToString()`, when you can just write `"\u03b1"`? (Even better would be what SLaks commented on your question.)

Comment: Due to some limitations I could not use other options - Thanks

Comment: @shahareldad: You can still use `"\u03b1"`